# Find the parameter "a" in this function $f(x)=x\sqrt{a-x^2}$

Tags: functions

How would I find parameter "a", given the domain of the function is : $-\sqrt{18}\leq x \leq \sqrt{18}$
$$f(x)=x\sqrt{a-x^2}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is only defined if $a-x^2\geq0$. Solving for x will result in

$$a\geq x^2$$
$$\sqrt{a} \geq |x|$$ 
$$-\sqrt{a}\leq x \leq \sqrt{a}$$

Compare that with your given domain and conclude that $a=18$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

For which $a$ do you have
$$a-x^2\geq 0\ \ ?$$